# Put a button outside of ... (3 dot) menu in actiobar

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar, styles, themes

In the action bar of my app I have just one button (share button) and it is in 3 dotted menu.
Action bar title is short and there is enough space for share button to be showing with icon (and not in 3 dotted menu).
this is my menu code:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:onClick="share"
    android:title="Share"
    android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_menu_share_mtrl_alpha"/></menu>
```

and this is the theme that i am using.

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#f60</item>
</style>
```

Thank you for answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That 3dot menu item is called the Overflow menu and it is set by default if you want to modify that you need to change the main menu xml file

Do the following:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<item
    android:title="share"
    android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
    android:icon= "@drawable/abc_ic_menu_share_mtrl_alpha"  
    android:orderInCategory="200"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

This row is the answer

```
android:showAsAction="always"
```

I was thinking that adding

```
app:showAsAction="always"
```

is enough but it wasn't.
Thank You :)

Comment: well i told the same thing

Comment: @rax  that's what our solution is correct ryt? so instead of marking it as solved this guy is making his own post

Comment: @rax : Your answer is all text but my exact answer was just this row. so you can change answer to exact row (answer) and i will choose it as the real answer.
And... no. What is revisions?